# Alternative to SQL BULK INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, .net-2.0

I need to import the data form .csv file into the database table (MS SQL Server 2005). SQL BULK INSERT seems like a good option, but the problem is that my DB server is not on the same box as my WEB server. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440289/ms-sql-server-bulk-insert-across-a-network) describes the same issue, however i don't have any control over my DB server, and can't share any folders on it.

I need a way to import my .csv programatically (C#), any ideas?

**EDIT:** this is a part of a website, where user can populate the table with .csv contents, and this would happen on a weekly basis, if not more often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up using [CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx). I saw a reference to it in one of the @Jon Skeet's answers, can't find it again to put the link to it

Answer (score 5):

You have several options:

1. [SSIS](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm)
2. [DTS](http://www.verio.com/support/documents/view_article.cfm?doc_id=3846)
3. custom application

Any of these approaches ought to get the job done.  If it is just scratch work it might be best to write a throwaway app in your favorite language just to get the data in.  If it needs to be a longer-living solution you may want to look into SSIS or DTS as they are made for this type of situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try Rhino-ETL, its an open source ETL engine written in C# that can even use BOO for simple ETL scripts so you don't need to compile it all the time.

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-etl

The guy who wrote it:
http://www.ayende.com/blog

The group lists have some discussions about it, I actually added bulk insert for boo scripts a while ago.
http://groups.google.com/group/rhino-tools-dev
http://groups.google.com/group/rhino-tools-dev/browse_thread/thread/2ecc765c1872df19/d640cd259ed493f1

If you download the code there are several samples, also check the google groups list if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

How big are your datasets?  Unless they are **very** large you can get away with parameterized insert statements.  You may want to load to a staging table first for peace of mind or performance reasons.

Comment: datasets go up to 10k records