# MS SQL Bulk Insert from local machine

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to MS SQL, and I ran into this problem: [Cannot bulk load. The file "c:\data.txt" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850205/cannot-bulk-load-the-file-c-data-txt-does-not-exist)

I am trying to give co-workers a custom query with variable input (they will use different input.txt daily). I understand that for Bulk Insert to work, the input file needs to be on the server.

There seem to be a couple of solutions: [MS SQL Server - Bulk Insert Across a Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440289/ms-sql-server-bulk-insert-across-a-network)

What would be the best way to upload a local file progmatically?

Comment: is there a common network share that they can all use?  i.e. \\server\allusers\data.txt  that everyone calling this bulk copy has access to?

Comment: Most of our employees only use the server through an MS Access UI, and we have FTP connections set up.

Comment: I'm making a folder that we can all share and access natively. Did you have an idea for something like that specifically?